# Ыуе ф Ашчув вшм ещ 100% of the parent container (whose width is set as a percentage, not pixels)

Tags: html, css

How can I create a container with `position: fixed;` that would occupy 100% of its parent container? The problem is that the width of the parent container is set not in pixels, but in percentages.

In the example below, the red container should have the same width as the green container, which width must remain equals to 100%.

```css
.parent{
  width: 50%;
  border: solid green 2px;
}
.child{
  height: 200px;
  border: solid red 2px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Text text text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Ыуе ф Ашчув вшм ещ ?

Comment: Don't used FIXED, use Sticky instead

Comment: @MisterJojo wow, this is what happens when a tired programmer types text without looking at the screen. Sorry, I'll delete this question and recreate it.

Comment: @MisterJojo It's supposed to be A fixed div that takes 100% of the parent container (whose width is set as a percentage, not pixels)

Comment: @Rumata ...and takes more than 10 hours to read the comments on his question, even those put in the 2 minutes after having posted it...

Comment: @MisterJojo Yes, sometimes. Due to timezone difference and multitasking. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: I have the feeling that you are insensitive to the negative image that this behavior generates...

Comment: @MisterJojo I may be wrong, but your reaction seems to me somewhat hostile, and I do not fully understand the reason for this. If I have a question at the end of the working day, I check the answers in the morning, taking into account the time zone difference, many colleagues will see my question when it's already late at night for me, so it makes sense. The fact that I made a typo in the title is indeed unfortunate and funny, I would be happy to correct it if it were possible.

Comment: @MisterJojo I respect the StackOverflow community and I've been here for quite some time. I don't see anything in this situation that would be worth your attention and precious time, but I would be glad to hear your point of view if you want to express it. I wish you a good day.

Comment: @MisterJojo ... And, If the Cyrillic alphabet annoyed you for other more political reasons, then I want to use this opportunity to tell you that I am against the war and against the criminal regime of dictator putin, I have many friends in Ukraine, I grieve and pray for the victims of this monstrous war and believe in the victory of Ukraine and its free people, as well as that one day Russia will also be free from dictatorship. Слава Україні!

Comment: Let's be Cartesian: SO is a stacking system at ~4 questions per minute.
So if you don't get an answer within a quarter of an hour, then your question goes to page 2 or 10 depending on the specificity of the tags chosen and may not find anyone to just read it, see the Viewed counter. In some cases your question may require time to craft an answer, but if your question requires clarification, you'll know within 10 minutes in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about inheriting the CSS width by applying this rule, `width: inherit;`

```css
.parent {
  width: 50%;
  border: solid green 2px;
}

.child {
  height: 200px;
  border: solid red 2px;
  position: fixed;
  width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Text text text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will delete and recreate this question feel free to add your answer there.

Comment: @Rumata this answer is simply wrong and doesn't make any sense ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif Would you mind proposing an alternative answer?